# post-hoc tests: pairwise.t.test versus TukeyHSD test

Tags: r

I created the following example to compare the two functions `pairwise.t.test()` and `TukeyHSD()`

```
x <- c(10,11,15,8,16,12,20)
y <- c(10,14,18,25,28,30,35)
z <- c(14,19,35,18,17,16,25)

d <- c(x,y,z)
f <- as.factor(c(rep("a",7), rep("b",7), rep("c",7)))

pairwise.t.test(d, f)
TukeyHSD(aov(d ~ f))
```

Is it normal that the p-values differ like that for these two tests? Is there a way to adjust parameters in both or one test(s) to make the p-values more equal?

Also, it seems that there is no parameter `var.equal` as it is the case for the `t.test()` for both tests. Is that really true?

Comment: Isn't it more suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I am always not sure when to post where. It seems there is no clear separation between stats.stackexchange and stackoverflow.

Comment: I think this should be moved to CV as your question relates to statistics more than it does to programming.

Comment: If your question requires is about statistics, then it's better suited for CV. If the question is how to get stuff done using R, then it's a programming question and belongs here, on SO. This question is kind of borderline, in my opinion, and I have no problem with it being here. If it doesn't get answered in 24 hours, then flag it for migration.

Answer (score 2):

From the help page for TukeyHSD:

> When comparing the means for the levels of a factor in an analysis of variance,
>   a simple comparison using t-tests will inflate the probability of declaring a 
>   significant difference when it is not in fact present. This because the intervals
>   are calculated with a given coverage probability for each interval but the
>   interpretation of the coverage is usually with respect to the entire family of
>   intervals.

The TukeyHSD test is a different test and, based on the the comments above, I would expect in general that it would give higher p-values. Having said that, for the data you supplied the p-values don't look dramatically different to me for inference purposes.

Comment: `pairwise.t.test` does adjustments for multiple comparisons, too, though, just using different methods.

Answer (score 2):

pairwise.t.test adjusts the p-values to adjust for multiple comparisons according to one of six methods (see ?p.adjust for details). To get separate standard deviation estimates instead of a pooled standard deviation, use the pool.SD=FALSE argument. There is no comparable option in analysis of variance which is what you are passing to the TukeyHSD() function.